# Facebook auto post module not posting to my FB page

Tags: 7, rules, social-network

When user comments on a particular node the comment title and comment body should be automatically posted to my Facebook page. For this I have used [Facebook autopost](https://www.drupal.org/project/fb_autopost). I have added my appid in fb_autopost configuration page and it displays the list of pages I manage and I have selected required page. Used below rules for auto posting comment in facebook

```
{ "rules_facebook_autopost_" : {
    "LABEL" : "Facebook Autopost ",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "fb_autopost_entity", "comment" ],
    "ON" : { "comment_insert--comment_node_theme_display" : { "bundle" : "comment_node_theme_display" } },
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_create" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "facebook_publication",
            "param_type" : "link",
            "param_user" : [ "site:current-user" ]
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "entity_created" : "Created entity" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "entity-created:field-facebook-message" ],
          "value" : "[comment:title]"
        }
      },
      { "publish_to_facebook" : {
          "USING" : { "publication" : [ "entity-created" ], "pages" : "1575855786569558" },
          "PROVIDE" : { "facebook_publication_id" : { "facebook_publication_id" : "Facebook publication returned ID" } }
        }
      },
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "success" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

After saving the comment it throws below error and comment not posting in Facebook.

> Facebook SDK threw an error: OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't
>   authorized the application to perform this action

How can I achieve this or Is there any other way to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Finally found the answer.

In `admin/config/services/fbpermissions` need to give Publish pages permission for users.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I never used this module before, so i just found this.

Please follow this page instruction for configuration
https://www.drupal.org/node/1914896